# How can I use this javascript function to add the value of the item to the value of the dropzone?

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop

I am building a craps game and have coind in denomination. they each contain a value tag. I got the coin to copy to the drop area but I want the value to add to the value of the drop area. and then use that as the total number bet.

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
    // makeBet(data);
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

Also I am working to get the game to report the bank is empty if the bet trys to exceed it.

```
#c10 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:48px; 
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background: yellow;
    color:#000;
    border: 6px solid black;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;  
    float: left;
    z-index: 7;
}

[draggable=true] {
    cursor: move;
}

<div id= "land" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" value="0">

<div id="c10" draggable="true" class="circle" ondragstart="drag(event)" value="10">10</div>
```

here is some more of the code. Again I want the value to add to the value of the landing then take that number as the bet.

Comment: You'll have to post a little more code, preferably in a fiddle. And please don't post the whole source code of your game :). Especially the HTML part may be interesting.

Comment: I don't know this "fiddle"

Comment: He means a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. It gets the value of the coin and adds it to the value of the target.
The [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)'s turn the the value attributes, which are strings, into integers.

```
function drop(ev) {
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var src = document.getElementById(data);
    var target = ev.target;
    target.appendChild(src.cloneNode(true));
    target.getAttribute('value') = parseInt(target.getAttribute('value')) + parseInt(src.getAttribute('value'));
    // makeBet(data);
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```